# Select is invisible because of linear-gradient in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a **select** box and I use a linear gradient as a **background**. In Firefox everything works fine, but in Chrome, I have to hover to see the options because the text is white and the background is white too. See the image bellow:

[image]

I'm think in removing the linear gradient, because **I can't** use jQuery, Javascript or PHP is OK. Someone knows the best way to solve this?

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/biibis/pen/EWpbxV) to help.

```css
select {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #12964f;
    background: linear-gradient(#4eba71, #12964f);
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="">first value</option>
    <option value="">second value</option>
    <option value="">third value</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
select {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #12964f;
    background: linear-gradient(#4eba71, #12964f);
}

select option {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="">first value</option>
    <option value="">second value</option>
    <option value="">third value</option>
</select>
```

You can add `color:#000` to the options, which won't affect the selected option.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWBOqx

Comment: Thank you, haslam! I forgot about that lol I'll accept your answer after 1 minute (site politics ahaha)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)